# How to setup networking for Linux Mint - VM when host machine uses a PAC file?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, software-installation

My host is a Windows 7 x64 machine. The office network uses a PAC file for the LAN settings. So, under Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings, I have Use automatic configuration script with an address for the PAC file.

My Linux Mint v14, runs on VMWare. The network settings of the VM is set to NAT. Now, if I specify the same on Firefox within Mint, I am able to browse the internet.

However, if I try to install software say gedit I get the problem.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: get the pac file, determine the proxy server and configure apt-get to use the proxy server

Comment: @UlrichDangel Thanks! I have the pac file. How do I configure apt-get to use proxy server? A little new to Linux.